# How to define regex in eql query which will identify any filename starts with "."

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to test eql query which will identify any filename starts with "." but getting an error.

```
GET /*/_eql/search  
{
  "query": """process where event.type in ("start", "process_started") and
  process.args: [/\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\-][a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]{1,254}/] and
  process.name not in ("ls", "find")
  """
}
```

error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "line 2:17: no viable alternative at input 'process.args: ['"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "line 2:17: no viable alternative at input 'process.args: ['",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "no_viable_alt_exception",
      "reason" : null
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

What's wrong with regex?

Answer (score 1):

```
process where event.type in ("start", "process_started") and
  process.args regex~ "\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-][a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]{1,254}" and
  not process.name in ("ls", "find")
```

Fixed!